# How do I solve $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x}-1}$ indeterminate limit without the L'hospital rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, radicals, indeterminate-forms

I've been trying to solve this limit without L'Hospital's rule because I don't know how to use derivates yet. So I tried rationalizing the denominator and numerator but it didn't work.

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x}-1}$

What is wrong with $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x^2}-1+1}{\sqrt{1+x}-1} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1+x}-1}{\sqrt{1+x}-1} + \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x}-1}$ = 1 + DIV?

Comment: What's DIV? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Gummybears:  I suppose DIV stands for the claim that this term is divergent which is certainly not true. See my answer below.

Comment: @Tintarn I know the answer :P

Comment: Hint $ \sqrt {1+y}=1+(y/2)(1+ k(y))$  where $ \lim_{y \to 0} k(y)=0,$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT 1:**

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x^2}&=\sqrt{1+x}\left(1-\sqrt{1-x}\right)\\\\
&=\sqrt{1+x}\,\,\left(\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1-x}}\right)
\end{align}$$

**HINT 2:**

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}-1}&=\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+1}{x}
\end{align}$$

Comment: The first one beaten me.

Comment: @deadbeef Don't worry.  You'll be fine.  ;-))  ... And thank you for the "best vote!!!"

Comment: Once again, clever answers to simple problems. Lot to learn. +1

Comment: @Shailesh Wow!  Thank you so much for your compliment and vote up!!  Each of us has a lot to learn.  And the more one learns, the more that becomes apparent.

Answer (score 3):

Notice, use rationalization as follows $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x}-1}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1+x-(1-x^2)}{1+x-1}\times \left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+1}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+x}{x}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+1}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0}(x+1)\left(\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+1}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)$$
$$=(0+1)\left( \frac{\sqrt{1+0}+1}{\sqrt{1+0}+\sqrt{1-0}}\right)$$
$$=1\left(\frac{2}{2}\right)=\color{red}{1}$$

Answer (score 2):

Set $x=\cos2y$

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x}-1} =\lim_{y\to\pi/4}\dfrac{\sqrt2\cos y-\sin2y}{\sqrt2\cos y-1}$$

$$=-\sqrt2\lim_{y\to\pi/4}\cos y\cdot\lim_{y\to\pi/4}\dfrac{\sin y-\sin\dfrac\pi4}{\cos y-\sin\dfrac\pi4}$$

**Method**$\#1:$
$$\lim_{y\to\pi/4}\dfrac{\sin y-\sin\dfrac\pi4}{\cos y-\sin\dfrac\pi4} =\dfrac{\lim_{y\to\pi/4}\dfrac{\sin y-\sin\dfrac\pi4}{y-\dfrac\pi4}}{\lim_{y\to\pi/4}\dfrac{\cos y-\cos\dfrac\pi4}{y-\dfrac\pi4}} =\dfrac{\dfrac{d(\sin y)}{dy}_{(\text{ at } y=\pi/4)}}{\dfrac{d(\cos y)}{dy}_{(\text{ at } y=\pi/4)}}$$

**Method**$\#2:$  Use [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) to get

$$\dfrac{\sin y-\sin\dfrac\pi4}{\cos y-\sin\dfrac\pi4}=\cdots=-\cot\dfrac{y+\pi/4}2$$

Comment: I guess the only possible explanation for why this wonderful answer was downvoted is because the OP apparently asked for what was wrong with his solution, rather than asking for a new approach. Anyway, that's exactly what I would have done, so $(+1)$.

Comment: Wonderful solution. +1. (Though that's not what the OP asked)

Answer (score 1):

Your argumentation is completely right until in the last step you claim that the second term is divergent which is not true. You rather have:
$$\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+x}-1}=\frac{x^2(\sqrt{1+x}+1)}{x(1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}=x\frac{\sqrt{1+x}+1}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
Now, the second factor clearly goes to 1 as $x$ approaches 0 and hence the whole term converges to 0 which makes your original term converge to $1+0=1$.

Note that your idea of rationalizing numerator *and* denominator was indeed a good approach...

Answer (score 0):

Without too many rationalizations: the term $\sqrt{1+x}$ appears several times. So, set $\sqrt{1+x}=1+t$, that makes $x=2t+t^2$ and $1-x=1-2t-t^2$; then your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1+t-(1+t)\sqrt{1-2t-t^2}}{t}=
\lim_{t\to0}(1+t)\cdot\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1-\sqrt{1-2t-t^2}}{t}
$$
provided the limit of the second factor exists; but
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1-\sqrt{1-2t-t^2}}{t}=
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1-(1-2t-t^2)}{t(1+\sqrt{1-2t-t^2})}
$$
with the usual rationalization. Can you go on?

Comment: Shouldn't this be the limit as $t \rightarrow 1$?

Comment: @AlfredYerger $t=\sqrt{1+x}-1$; if $x\to0$, then …

Comment: oh! I misread your substitution. Very sorry.

Comment: @AlfredYerger Never mind!